# Change error message in fine-upload

Tags: javascript, laravel, fine-uploader

I want to change error msg from "Upload failed" to server error msg / for example: file: ["The file must be a file of type: mp4."]
I find somethink like this:

```
  <script>
  function createUploader() {
    var faileduploader = new qq.FineUploader({
      element: document.getElementById('fine-uploader'),
      autoUpload: true,
      failedUploadTextDisplay: {
        mode: 'custom',
        maxChars: 40,
        responseProperty: 'error',
        enableTooltip: true
      },
      debug: true
    });
  }

  window.onload = createUploader;
</script>
```

but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

In order to display a custom error message from your server, the server must return an "error" property with the error message in its JSON response to the upload request. This is covered in the error message section of the docs at http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/handling-errors.html.